# How to check user authorized with filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have a filter and Login Servlet. How i can check - authorized user or not? and if not authorized - to redirect him to Login Servlet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

1. When user logs in, set `User` object for that user in HttpSession. This way, `httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_USER", userObject)`
2. Now, every time you hit the filter/security filter. The first thing you do is check for this attribute.
3. If the attribute is not there, redirect/forward the request to login servlet.

The pseudo code would look like this:

```
//in your login servlet, on successful login
request.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_USER", userObject);

//in your security filter
if(request.getSession().getAttribute("LOGGED_USER") == null){
//optionally, you may like to check if that attribute has a valid userId as well
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("relative/path/to/login/servlet")
     rd.forward(request, response);
     return;
}
```

---

*Edit 1:* **see this** http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html

Answer (score 2):

In filter:
IF UserObjectInSession exists => user logged
ELSE do redirect to servlet

In servlet:
IF verification() will be correct => put UserObjectInSession to session

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {       
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
    HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession();
    User currentUser = (User)session.getAttribute("userInSession");

    if (currentUser == null) {
        httpRes.sendRedirect("...")    //redirect to LoginServlet
    } else {        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```