# authentication valid user

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee

Java EE.

Ok, JSP form handed to servlet username and password. Username and password is vaild.

How i can AUTHenticate the user?

Thanks for help.

Comment: you could have updated your older question. Which is almost the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985133/how-to-check-user-authorized-with-filter

Comment: :) so, after `httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute("LOGGED_USER", userObject)` you just use `RequestDispatcher` or `request.sendRedirect` to redirect the user to desired page.

Comment: Nishant: is another. There I asked - how do you know the user logged in or not. and here I ask how his log :)

Comment: may I ask stupid questions.
but I have some problems understanding java ee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exacly problem you have. Try this steps:

1. Submit your form in HTTP GET to your LoginServlet
2. Get Login
3. Get Password
4. If Login && Password are correct create some UserObject and call httpRequest.getSession() which get user http session. Then put this object to your created session.
5. To check if user is logged you check if userObject exists in session

If you will have problems try attached your current sources.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the tutorial:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html

Don't reinvent the wheel - especially not security, as it is hard enough to get it right even when using existing frameworks.